# Выборка из трех таблиц MySQL

Tags: mysql

Добрый день!

Помогите с запросом.
Есть 3 таблицы, с данными вида:

```
  id1 | name |
   1  | var1 |  
   2  | var2 |

  id2 | id1 | note 
   1  | 1   | asd  
   2  | 1   | asd  
   3  | 2   | dsa

  id3 | id1 | text  
  3   | 1   | asdf  
  4   | 1   | fsds  
  5   | 2   | as44
```

Надо выбрать строки из 1-ой таблицы (`id1`, `name`) и строки связанные по id1 из второй и третьей таблиц, но чтобы из второй таблицы выбиралась строка с максимальным id2, а из третьей с максимальным id3.
Соответственно 1 записи из таблицы 1, должна соответствовать 1 запись из таблицы 2 и 1 запись из таблицы 3.

Можно ли это сделать 1 запросом?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Немного упорядочил код, чтобы понятнее было, что с чем связано. Схема:

```
CREATE TABLE main (
  id INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  name TEXT
) ENGINE=INNODB;

CREATE TABLE sub1 (
  id INT NOT NULL,
  id_main INT,
  note text,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  FOREIGN KEY (id_main) REFERENCES main(id)
) ENGINE=INNODB;

CREATE TABLE sub2 (
  id int NOT NULL,
  id_main INT,
  txt text,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  FOREIGN KEY (id_main) REFERENCES main(id)
) ENGINE=INNODB;

INSERT INTO main (id,name) VALUES
(1,'var1'),
(2,'var2');

INSERT INTO sub1 (id,id_main,note) VALUES
(1,1,'asd'),
(2,1,'asd'),
(3,2,'asd');

INSERT INTO sub2 (id,id_main,txt) VALUES
(3,1,'asd'),
(4,1,'asd'),
(5,2,'asd');
```

Собственно запрос:

```
SELECT m.id, m.name, s1.s1id, s1.note, s2.s2id, s2.txt
FROM main m,
(SELECT max(id) as s1id, id_main, note FROM sub1 GROUP BY id_main) AS s1,
(SELECT max(id) as s2id, id_main, txt FROM sub2 GROUP BY id_main) AS s2
WHERE s1.id_main = m.id
AND s2.id_main = m.id
```

[Демо (sqlfiddle.com)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/98bd5/4/0)

Answer (score 2):

Можно. Капайте в сторону join, group. max и where. Может быть ещё union.

Вам надо выбрать все записи первой таблицы, сделать джоин со второй и третей, сделать группировку по id2 или id3 (и остальным не агригирующим полям)поля (а может и вместе, думаю когда разберётесь поймёте) и воспользоватся функцией max.

**можете добавить ещё вложенные запросы** :-)

Документацию по использованию выражение select можете посмотреть [тут](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html)

Comment: Да вот экспериментировал я и с group и c макс и с джойнами...    Но не получается нифига так сделать :(...  
Была мысль как-то задать в условие MAX
типа  
HAVING MAX()  
но не работает...

Comment: А Вы опишите что конкретно Вы делали, и как не получается. Принципиально не буду писать готовый ответ, без возможности оценить Ваши муки и страдания :-D Схему как можно получить нужный результат, применив знания из документации MySql, я описал в ответе.

Comment: Решил все же разбить запрос на 3 шт. так получается быстрей.

Comment: @Nikki: получается быстрее время выполнения, или быстрее написать код? Приведёте для нас медленный вариант без разбивки запроса?

Comment: Left Join и HAVING Вам в помощь (: